# What's the problem with these imports?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm getting these errors when trying to build the projects:

```
F:\Sistemas\Java\PDA\src\java\br\inf\ibs\mentawai\consequence\TypeConsequence.java:10: package javax.servlet does not exist
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
F:\Sistemas\Java\PDA\src\java\br\inf\ibs\mentawai\consequence\TypeConsequence.java:11: package javax.servlet does not exist
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
```

Comment: Just curious. What is a TypeConsequence from Mentawai? You can use the Mentawai forum for support with the framework. http://forum.mentaframework.org

Answer (score 3):

It means that servlet.jar isn't in your classpath, basically... I haven't used NetBeans myself, so I don't know how you tell it about libraries - but you need to do so :)

Comment: Netbeans uses the server jar instead of direct referenced jars to servlers, but even importing it directly, it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a web application, make sure that you have a server defined, the server provides those classes, however if you do not have a web application and you are just trying to compile a library that uses those classes, then you need to manually add the library to your project as jon suggested.

Comment: I've tried to add servlets-api.jar to the project manually and it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: That's what i'm doing all the time :(